# What could be causing duplicate log entries to be created in a custom PHP logging functionality?

Tags: php, .htaccess, logging

I have built a custom PHP system with a logging functionality with `Report::error|notice|warning` methods that invoke `Report::write()` to create a log report. However, during basic testing, I noticed that all my logs were written twice with identical timestamps.

```php
class Report {

    public static function write(string $file, string $message, string $level = 'notice'): bool {

        $extension  = '.log';
        $directory  = dirname(__DIR__, 1) . '/reports';
        $file       = sprintf('%s/%s%s', $directory, $file, $extension);
        $levels     = ['warning', 'notice', 'error', 'exception', "success"];

        // Ensure log directory exists; if not, create it
        if (!is_dir($directory)) {
            mkdir($directory, 0777, true);
        }
        
        // TODO: Regex the file name

        // Validate log level
        if (!in_array(strtolower($level), $levels)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        // Set the color code:
        if     ($level === "success")   { $color = ""; }  // Success
        elseif ($level === "notice")    { $color = ""; }  // Notice
        elseif ($level === "warning")   { $color = ""; }  // Warning
        elseif ($level === "error")     { $color = ""; }  // Error
        elseif ($level === "exception") { $color = ""; }  // Exception

        // Get the file name and line number where the error occurred
        $backtrace  = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 2);
        $line       = $backtrace[1]['line'];
        $fname      = $backtrace[1]['file'];
        
        // Write the message to the log file, including the file name and line number
        $message = sprintf('%s %s [%s] %s Line %d: %s', $color, date('d-m-Y H:i:s'), strtoupper($level), $fname, $line, $message);

        // This happens twice
        if (!file_put_contents($file, $message . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        // Stop script execution if the log level is "error"
        if (strtolower($level) === 'error') {
            exit; // <- We exit the code, but the above gets triggered twice
        }
        
        return true;
    }

    public static function notice(string $message): void {
        Report::write('notice', $message, 'notice');
    }
}
```

I also have a `controller.php` with some basic `HTML` and the call to the `Report::notice()` function.

```php
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    if(Report::notice("Page loaded")){ // This gets logged twice
        echo("Component created");     // This happens once
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

> `27-04-2023 07:49:42 [NOTICE] public/controller.php Line 46: Page loaded`
>
> `27-04-2023 07:49:42 [NOTICE] public/controller.php Line 46: Page loaded`

When the front-controllers `.htaccess` is removed, it removes the duplicates.

```
# Set rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to the front controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ controller.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

# Remove index listing
Options -Indexes

# Index file
DirectoryIndex controller.php
```

Can anyone help me identify what could be causing this bug and how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure you're not calling `Component::create` twice. The first time it creates the component successfully, the second time it fails because it's already been created

Comment: I have checked everywhere and it is only called once. I even made a global counter to calculate each time the function is called. Also I tested it with `Report::error()` which will `exit` the code, but it still happens twice.

Comment: Try adding `Report::notice("Component '{$component}' being created");` at the top of your create class, see how many times that is called. You can also try logging a back trace to see if you can track it down that way

Comment: Hmm... I tried `Report::notice()` alone in my `test.php` and it also shows twice. So it's not caused by the `Component::create()` function.

Comment: I think I have found the cause of the issue. It seems to only happen when my front-controller `.htaccess` is on. I may need to pull this question out and write completely new one at this point. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Go check what requests are actually happening, in your browser dev tools. It could be something like the browser making an automatic request for `/favicon.ico`, and if you do not have such a file ... then your rewrite setup will rewrite that request to your controller.php, too.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Indeed the browser tries to look for the favicon and triggers the `Report::notice` again. Simply adding a favicon fixes the issue. However, I will have to look more deeply into the front controller to prevent this if no favicon is available.

Thank you so much @CBroe, for your help!

Comment: Yeah, your controller isn't doing much "controlling" at the moment :-) Since the web server will now pass _all_ requests it can not match to an existing file or folder, to your controller.php, the complete 404 error handling now falls under your script's responsibilities - so this does not affect only a request for a favicon, but any other "faulty" requests that might come in from anywhere.

Comment: If your script can't find any content to show for the passed `page` parameter value (by looking it up in a database, or whatever) - then your controller should respond with a 404 status code, and an error document informing the user.

Comment: Yes of course, I had removed the `controller.php`functionality to test the class functionality "faster". And here we are now ‍♂️